# docker login x509: certificate is valid for, not

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-repository

I searched long and hard on google, but i'm no good with DNS / SSL.

We have 2 servers.. One for a private docker registry (serverA). and one for the application (serverB).

Local: do '**docker login registry.juistbezorgd.nl**', it shows Login Success

VPS: do '**docker login registry.juistbezorgd.nl**', gives this error ->

**x509: certificate is valid for www78.totaalholding.nl, www.www78.totaalholding.nl, not registry.juistbezorgd.nl**

But its strange, cause I checked the certifcates online and they all give back *.juistbezorgd.nl for 'registry.juistbezorgd.nl'.

I do have NGINX between it, that is running on ServerA and redirects all registry.juistbezorgd.nl to serverB

```
upstream registry {
  ip_hash;
  server 136.144.131.3:4001;
}

# registry
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # listen 80;
    server_name registry.juistbezorgd.nl www.registry.juistbezorgd.nl;
    client_max_body_size 1G;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_certificate /usr/src/app/ssl/live/juistbezorgd.nl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/src/app/ssl/live/juistbezorgd.nl/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://registry;
    }
}
```

Even then I don't understand why 'registry.juistbezorgd.nl' returns just valid, local login works, but just not on the VPS / Jenkins.

Comment: I too am using a private docker registry however its on same physical VPS machine as the server daemons my app run as so since traffic to-from the registry are always local to same box, and I do not expose to outside world the  registry ports, I avoid using https for that traffic ... not a solution just an alternative

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Its a pain in the ass with HTTPS, thats for sure. Maybe we should try skipping HTTPS also, but we are building docker containers in jenkins and want to upload them to private registry.. Could be done with --insecure flag I guess

Comment: I use letsencrypt so its very easy to re-generate the tls certs and just add `registry.juistbezorgd.nl`